Are, True and False just that, Two Values?
As I read Logic, I cannot help but notice that I am inundated with "True" and "False".
Logic, it seems, is nothing but "True" and "False"; everything, no matter how complicated, leads to either True or False! So I started thinking, if something is so important, in a subject that's so important, can it be just a value? SURELY there must be more to them than is obvious.
Wanted to get an opinion of Logicians out here; are there other thoughts, papers about it? I am interested in your thoughts actually, it's more insightful, as you know them more intimately, DEFINITELY MORE than me. Is there more to them or are they just two values?

Yes --many-valued logics are plentiful: fuzzy logic, three-valued logic, supervaluationism, dialetheism, paraconsistent logic etc

The process of going from the super important and central intuitions of right/ wrong, good/ bad, true/false to (classic 2 valued) logic is the route from meta to object language/level. Intuitively that seems backward because 'meta' suggests a 2nd. That happens because a professional logician has given you a cooked firmalization. If instead a historian were to describe the process from informal reasoning to its formalization there would be no such confusion

I'm not quite sure what you are asking. You can do classical logic with an arbitrary pair of values such as 0 and 1. We often use true and false because those are semantic concepts that are important. Are you asking whether the choice of values is arbitrary, or whether there are logics that are not bivalent, or something else?

It could be entirely reversed in the sense that True and False happen to be just two existential witnesses to introduce you to a universal generalization in such a way that the said universal active image flowing around and washing away any remaining confusions in your mind no longer depends on the two witnesses called True and False token values, or any other number of or even infinite number of token values...

@DoubleKnot See I realised that True is not a value at all. If you look at language, the way it is spoken it favours True. Example "pVq": Either p OR q", but this sentence is not explicit, it should be "Either p (is true) OR q (is True), (for the equation to be true)". Implicitely it talks about true value. It's True and "Other than True". True or Truth is something that keeps everything moving, base of everything. ONLY UPON BEING TRUE does this WORLD FUNCTION, otherwise nothing would happen. No laws, principles nothing would hold if it's not True. Truth is THE ONLY REAL PRIMITIVE IN LOGIC....

@DoubleKnot It's something like, why do theorems and laws of Math apply to this Universe so well and WHAT KEEPS THEM TRUE EVERYDAY?! WHY does anything in Universe Obey ANY LAWS AT ALL?!

True and False values as witness of their respective types are nothing but 'proofs' of the said types per the famous Curry-Howard correspondence applied to modern type theory, so we can generalize universally via their a priori proof sense instead of a posteriori witness sense in order to understand their ubiquitous existence. Or viewed alternatively like Frege, their token values actually introduce you and point to the objective landscape-fixing reference objects while the propositions in your mind symbolically or as images are mere proper names of the two objects, usually the true one...

The objection you make in the question seems to be something like: true and false aren't just values, they also have meanings. But the same is true of numbers like 11 and 23, which in addition to being values that a variable or expression might take, also mean something. (Actually, a number like 11 could mean several different things in different contexts.) So really the answer depends on whether you consider "meaning" to be part of what mathematical values are, or something beyond them.

@kaya3 hey hey hey, it's like someone opened up the flood gates of "since...therefore..." :). No what I meant was, to consider them "just values" is actually injustice on the Student. True is something that makes this Universe tick, True is something because of which, any law holds, you may confine, imprison actually, you may imprison it as a "value" in Logic but what is "True", "Truth". As I read Logic books multiple times I am starting to understand them, but I sometimes wonder, why do I understand now, why I didn't understand it the first time. What is it that I see now that makes me+

@kaya3 understand these complicated Logical expressions now versus before?!!! My very strong hunch is, THAT IT'S  "THE TRUTH" THAT I SEE...

So you're literally discovering the truth which is not false and fake instead of inventing some truth value standing there in front of your students?...

@DoubleKnot I am literally looking at the possibility of discovering "The Truth" hidden in Everything out there and I MUST SAY your cryptic comments are like spice in this otherwise "orderly bland world"...
I am the teacher and mercifully I am the student as well and both Teacher and Student are discovering The Truth and amazingly it is more "material" under the subject called "Logic" than it is in any Spiritual Book I have read till now....

See Yaroslav Shramko & Heinrich Wansing, Truth and Falsehood: An Inquiry into Generalized Logical Values (Springer, 2011), page 1:

The notion of a truth value was explicitly introduced into logic and philosophy
by Gottlob Frege — for the first time in Function und Begriff (1891) and most notably in his seminal paper Über Sinn und Bedeutung (1892). Frege conceived this notion as a natural component of his language analysis where sentences, being saturated expressions, are interpreted as a special kind of names, which refer to (denote, designate, signify) a special kind of objects: truth values. Moreover, there are, according to Frege, only two such objects: the True (das Wahre) and the False (das Falsche):


"A sentence proper is a proper name, and its Bedeutung, if it has one, is a truth-value: the True or the False."


It is worth noticing that Frege’s own attitude towards truth values was expressly
platonic. He considered them to be not simply ‘‘introduced’’ or ‘‘invented’’ but
virtually ‘‘discovered’’ entities, regarding himself, in this respect, as acting just like a chemist discovering new chemical elements [Einleitung in die Logik, 1990 edition, p. 88].


From the structuralist point of view, if we claimed "true" and "false" are two arbitrary values, replaceable by any other names, like "+" and "x", we would have a formal system which would have some of the behavior of our intuitive understanding of true and false, but not all of it.
Let's say there are notions (i.e. sentences, propositions) which get associated to "true" or "false", to represent a way of "evaluating" the notions:
eval(Notion1) -> True

eval(Notion2) -> False

eval(Notion3) -> False

In this model of truth-hood and falsehood, a notion can only evaluate to one value - not "true" and "false", like this:
eval(Notion4) -> True

eval(Notion4) -> False

This suggests we understand the structure of 'veracity' to be functional; i.e., in mathematics, there is a structure which has that behavior of "a thing can only get assigned one value": a function.
Actually, so far this is a partial function, because we haven't asserted that every notion has to be evaluable. Maybe some notions don't evaluate, because we don't know if they are true or false, or they intrinsically are unevaluable, or some other reason.
It's possible that in some situation, for some purpose, intent, or need, the above structural model of notions evaluating to one of two values is enough for our needs.
Or maybe it isn't. For example, consider a scenario in which you want to draw the inference that if a notion is false, then there's some other notion - an opposite notion - which is true. This requires us to add in more structure. We can add in a way of marking a notion so that it becomes its "opposite" notion, like this:
opposite(Notion1)

We can assert a rule, such as:
"If Notion1 evaluates to true, then opposite(Notion1) evaluates to false. And if Notion1 evaluates to false, then opposite(Notion1) evaluates to true."
The above rule is a particular choice which affects the behavior of the model. It isn't an inevitable choice of rule. We could have chosen just the first half:
"If Notion1 evaluates to true, then opposite(Notion1) evaluates to false."
In that case, it isn't clear what the opposite of a false notion evaluates to. Even so, there's nothing wrong with such a model. If we want our model to act that way, then it's the model we want. But if we want our model to treat "true" as the opposite of "false" and vice versa, then we need the first version of the rule.
Mathematics has structures which can act in accordance with such a rule. We can say that "opposite" is a function which takes a notion which evaluates to true, and turns it into some other notion which evaluates to false:
opposite : Notion -> Notion,
where if evaluate(notion) -> true,
then evaluate(opposite(notion)) ->  false,
and if evaluate(notion) -> false,
then evaluate(opposite(notion) -> true.

But we can keep developing the model. The above is kind of clunky. We could define an operation on the values "true" and "false" themselves, as:
opposite(true) = false

opposite(false) = true

And then we can make an operation on notions, also called "opposite", and then we could say:
for all notions,
evaluate(opposite(notion)) =
opposite(evaluate(notion))

In this scenario, "opposite" is acting like the more familiar word "not":
If "It is raining" is false, then "It is not raining" is true.

The point is, there is still more structure to model, if we want to. For example, one can notice that "not" tends to be self-cancelling: "It is not not raining" means "It is raining". And we can add this into our model, which is taking more and more mathematical shape:

We have a collection of values (a set, or a type) Bool, whose only members are "true" and "false".
We have another collection of values, Notion.
We have a relation on the members of Bool, "not", with these properties:

for all x in Bool, not(not(x)) = x
not(true) = false


We have a relation between Notion and Bool, "evaluate", assigning a value of Notion to a value of Bool
We have a relation between Notion and Notion, "opposite", assigning a notion to another notion, with this property:

evaluate(opposite(notion)) = opposite(evaluate(notion))



And it doesn't stop there. Sometimes we want to combine the meaning of two notions. Let's call this relation "combine". We want to combine them in such a way where if both notions evaluate to true, then the combination of the notions also evaluates to true. Then let's say:
If Notion1 -> true and Notion2 -> true, then combine(Notion1, Notion2) -> true.

If combine(Notion1, Notion2) -> true, then Notion1 -> true and Notion2 -> true.

The above rule characterizes some of the behavior of the word "and": if it is raining, and it is windy, then it is "raining and windy".
So that's one way of looking at whether or not True and False are "arbitrary values": you can model something that way, but if you want the model to have certain behavior, you have to add in rules and structure to make it act that way. We could say that the behavior of true and false as we know them can be constructed; so that's their "meaning" lies not inside them a priori, but emerges outside them given how they interact with and relate to each other in an enclosing system.
A structure which models the relationship of "true" and "false" to each other through classic logical operations like "and", "or", "not", and "implies", is called a Boolean algebra.

Hi Julius, I was talking about what they are when the bestest word that we can come up with is "notion" and quite honestly for the word "notion" itself to have a consistent meaning everyday, there has to be Some Kind of Truth that holds these scribblings to one consistent meaning day after day. So in the base of Everything there is True. In that sense it is indescribable. For "False" to consistently mean one thing, something, something behind the scenes must Hold, remain True , EVERY SINGLE DAY. It's like trying to describe God, WHO IS THE BASE OF ALL, WITHOUT HIM, There is NO OBSERVER...

And not from the point of view of use in a or by a System...

Are True or False themselves propositions?
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3053336/are-true-or-false-themselves-propositions
True, False are commonly described as values or as propositional constants.
In the Cartesian plane we denote relations {1,1} or {-1,1} as coordinate pairs. In propositional calculus a proposition, by definition, must form a logical relation with one of two possible values or constants: True or not-True. False is another symbol to indicate not-True.
SEP - Propositional Logic
https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-propositional/

In presenting propositional logic, we will not assume any particular theory of propositions. As we will see, the development of and plurality of systems of propositional logic can only be appreciated when no particular conception of proposition is in place. The only stipulations are that the connectives operate always on whole sentences and never on sub-sentential items like predicates or terms, and that they create sentences in the same evaluation class as the ones they operate on, never higher-order expressions about the sentences in that class.

